# JMeter Load testing of API in WSO2 API Gateway

Tags: jmeter, wso2, load-testing, wso2-api-manager, jmeter-plugins

In my current project we want to implement high performance test procedures and monitoring in WSO2 and in the API gateway area. Unfortunately there is little or no documentation to help me. Has any of you ever built such a scenario?

I am very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Load testing of WSO2-hosted webservices isn't different from any other web services, to wit you should be able to use:

1. Normal JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to execut [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET), [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST), [PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT), [DELETE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE), etc. requests against the API endpoints
2. [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send headers like [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)
3. [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) for extracting dynamic data for [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) purposes

More information:

- [Load Testing Published APIs with JMeter](https://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/load-testing-published-apis-with-jmeter/)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)

Answer (score 2):

You can refer https://github.com/wso2/performance-apim. In this, it has done some load testing for the API gateway. There it uses slow backends, API mediations, etc. Maybe you can reuse some of the JMeter scripts.